# Загрузка модели нейронной сети load_model

Tags: python, keras, jupyter-notebook

При загрузке

```
mod = load_model("C:\1.h5")
```

выходит ошибка

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-77b429e24014> in <module>()
----> 1 mod = load_model("C:\1.h5")

~\Anaconda3\envs\cryp\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\saving.py in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
    247     opened_new_file = not isinstance(filepath, h5py.File)
    248     if opened_new_file:
--> 249         f = h5py.File(filepath, mode='r')
    250     else:
    251         f = filepath

~\Anaconda3\envs\cryp\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py in __init__(self, name, mode, driver, libver, userblock_size, swmr, **kwds)
    310             with phil:
    311                 fapl = make_fapl(driver, libver, **kwds)
--> 312                 fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
    313 
    314                 if swmr_support:

~\Anaconda3\envs\cryp\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py in make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, fcpl, swmr)
    140         if swmr and swmr_support:
    141             flags |= h5f.ACC_SWMR_READ
--> 142         fid = h5f.open(name, flags, fapl=fapl)
    143     elif mode == 'r+':
    144         fid = h5f.open(name, h5f.ACC_RDWR, fapl=fapl)

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py\h5f.pyx in h5py.h5f.open()

OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'C:.h5', errno = 22, error message = 'Invalid argument', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

замените:

```
mod = load_model("C:\1.h5")
```

на:

```
mod = load_model(r"C:\1.h5")
#        NOTE:   ^
```

---

`"\1"` - это UNICODE символ с кодом `1`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ValueError: Unknown layer:layers вышло

Comment: @rowwwansl, `ValueError: Unknown layer:layers` никак не связано с вашим вопросом. Очевидно следует открыть новый SO вопрос...